# Untangling the cause of an error in Theano

Tags: python, theano

I have a bug in my code, but finding the exact cause of it is difficult because of how theano works.

Following the tips in the exception details, I set `theano.config.optimizer='None'` and `theano.config.exception_verbosity='high'`, but that doesn't tell me enough.

In my case, for example, there is a problem with the dot product between two tensors. The stacktrace leads me through a lot and to a particular function which seems  to contain in it, somewhere, the problematic call to `theano.tensor.dot`, but I can't find where exactly that part of the code is, and since I'm trying to implement things through keras, it gets even more complicated and tangled up.

Is there any way to get more details on an apply node? I've tried using [StepMode](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/sandbox/debugging_with_stepmode.html), as it seems to be attached to the nodes, but if there is a way of making that tool print the exact lines from which the code in the node is executed, I don't know what it is. I tried using that to print a stacktrace when the problem occurs, but it prints just about the same stacktrace as the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the spots in your code that use `theano.tensor.dot` you can monkeypatch it with wrapper code that uses `traceback.print_stack`:

```
import traceback
original_dot = theano.tensor.dot

def debug_wrapper(*args,**kw):
    traceback.print_stack()
    return original_dot(*args,**kw)
theano.tensor.dot = debug_wrapper
```

This way any time `theano.tensor.dot` is called (after it is patched) it will show you the stack like the one in a traceback message and still do it's job.  Note that I am not very familiar with theano so this is a general python debugging solution, there might well be ways specific to theano that let you do similar.

Comment: Thank you! I was actually thinking about doing something of the sorts. In fact, I put stacktraces in other places, but somehow it didn't occur to me to just place it in the problematic function itself. I'll try it tomorrow, since it's already very late

Answer (score 0):

You should try using theano [test_values](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/debug_faq.html#using-test-values). That way the exception will be raised exactly on the line where the error occurs and not after the compilation of the graph.

You need to change the `theano.config.compute_test_value` flag to `'raise'` so that you get an error if there is an input tensor without a test_value, to make sure that all of the test computation will be propagated to the point where your error occurs.